# Is there any way to skip macro replacement(During preprocessing) when macro is used as a variable name?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, macros, qt5

**ConflictHeader.h**

```
      #define _c 6 //This is third party header, canot change, since
// there is no sorce code to rebuild
```

**testclass.h**

```
    #ifndef TESTCLASS_H
    #define TESTCLASS_H

    #include <QObject>
    #include "ConflictHeader.h"//Include conflicted header

    class TestClass : public QObject
    {
      Q_OBJECT

    public:
        TestClass(QObject *parent);
        ~TestClass();
    private:

    };
    #endif // TESTCLASS_H
```

**testclass.cpp**

```
#include "testclass.h"

TestClass::TestClass(QObject *parent)
  : QObject(parent)
{

}    
TestClass::~TestClass()
{

}
```

**moc_testclass.cpp**

> This is generated by MOC compiler, Please note function where compilation issue comes
>   "int TestClass::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call **_c**, int _id, void **_a)"

```
/****************************************************************************
** Meta object code from reading C++ file 'testclass.h'
**
** Created: Wed Jun 10 11:24:06 2015
**      by: The Qt Meta Object Compiler version 62 (Qt 4.7.4)
**
** WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!
*****************************************************************************/

#include "../../testclass.h"
#if !defined(Q_MOC_OUTPUT_REVISION)
#error "The header file 'testclass.h' doesn't include <QObject>."
#elif Q_MOC_OUTPUT_REVISION != 62
#error "This file was generated using the moc from 4.7.4. It"
#error "cannot be used with the include files from this version of Qt."
#error "(The moc has changed too much.)"
#endif

QT_BEGIN_MOC_NAMESPACE
static const uint qt_meta_data_TestClass[] = {

 // content:
       5,       // revision
       0,       // classname
       0,    0, // classinfo
       0,    0, // methods
       0,    0, // properties
       0,    0, // enums/sets
       0,    0, // constructors
       0,       // flags
       0,       // signalCount

       0        // eod
};

static const char qt_meta_stringdata_TestClass[] = {
    "TestClass\0"
};

const QMetaObject TestClass::staticMetaObject = {
    { &QObject::staticMetaObject, qt_meta_stringdata_TestClass,
      qt_meta_data_TestClass, 0 }
};

#ifdef Q_NO_DATA_RELOCATION
const QMetaObject &TestClass::getStaticMetaObject() { return staticMetaObject; }
#endif //Q_NO_DATA_RELOCATION

const QMetaObject *TestClass::metaObject() const
{
    return QObject::d_ptr->metaObject ? QObject::d_ptr->metaObject : &staticMetaObject;
}

void *TestClass::qt_metacast(const char *_clname)
{
    if (!_clname) return 0;
    if (!strcmp(_clname, qt_meta_stringdata_TestClass))
        return static_cast<void*>(const_cast< TestClass*>(this));
    return QObject::qt_metacast(_clname);
}

int TestClass::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call _c, int _id, void **_a)
{
    _id = QObject::qt_metacall(_c, _id, _a);
    if (_id < 0)
        return _id;
    return _id;
}
QT_END_MOC_NAMESPACE
```

> Compiler output error 1>.\GeneratedFiles\Debug\moc_testclass.cpp(62) :
>   error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'constant'

So I cannot change "_c" in either "ConflictHeader.h"( thirdparty lib) and "moc_testclass.cpp"( moc generated ).

**Is there any way to skip macro replacement(During preprocessing) when macro is used as a variable name?**

Comment: It is unfortunate that the code generator uses `PARENT` as an argument name. All caps symbols are often macros.

Comment: Does undef right after the include of conflictingheader.h work?

Comment: Yes compilation issue is solved as a workaround. by using #undef, But I think there is no way in C++ to provide conditional skip on macro replacement(During preprocessing) , in my case "variable name _c". If that is available then it would be nice to avoid conflicts. but it is practically violate preprocessing rule.. Please update, if any one have other idea on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to fix that problem by using:

```
#include "ConflictHeader.h"//Include conflicted header
#ifdef _c
#undef _c
#endif
```

A better option might be to create a wrapper .h file fro `ConflictHeader.h` and use the wrappr .h file in rest of your code.

ConflictHeaderW.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "ConflictHeader.h"
#ifdef _c
#undef _c
#endif

// #undef anything else that create problems.
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `#undef` preprocessor directive to undefine the macro.

More info: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Undefining-and-Redefining-Macros.html